# Normal Subgroups implies...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ $\le$ $G$ such that $[G:H]=n<\infty$. Assume that $H\unlhd G$. Show that for all $g \epsilon G\ ,\ g^n \epsilon \ H$.

---

What I've figured out so far is the since $H$ is normal to $G$, $[G:H] = [H:G]$. Also I think the fact that the index is finite should be helpful, though I'm not sure how yet...

Answer (score 1):

The factor group $\;G/H\;$ has order $\;n\;$  and then for all $\;g\in G\;,\;\;(gH)^n=H\;$